# Next JS Image Component works for static image files, but dynamic urls fail to load images

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am using NextJS `<Image />` component. I am using both local image sources and sources from external API. Everything works in my local development environment, but as soon as I host it on the server to production, dynamic images from API are not showing up.

```js
<Image
  src="house.jpg"   // loaded from local and works fine
  alt="Picture of my house."
  width={250}
  height={250}
/>
```

The code below works in dev environment, but not in production server.

```js
const renderHouses = (apiHouses) => (
   apiHouses.map(house => (
      <div key={house.id}>
         <Image
           src={house.img}   // not working (loading) on production server
           alt={`Picture of ${house.name}`}
           width={250}
           height={250}
         /> 
      </div>
   ))
)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yep, it will work for your localhost, but external images would not be loaded in production env if you don't specify the `domain` name in your `next.config.js` file.

```js
module.exports = {
  images: {
    domains: ['localhost','yourDomainName.com'],
  },
};
```

You can find more info [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image).

Comment: Yes, and don't forget to restart your Next app for it to be taken into account.